# $PATH messed up. How did this happen and how to change back to default

Tags: command-line, terminal, path

My $PATH comes up as:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands

I'm not sure how this happened but how do I change it back to the default PATH?

Answer (score 1):

What is your system?

Ubuntu default path is
`/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

if you want to change this back to the default, you need to opne your .bashrc file on your home and change it in there:

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I am on a 2019 iMac running the Big Sur OS. It's default is zshell, not bash